# How do i change the visibility of an existing block programmatically?

Tags: 8, blocks

How do i change the visibility of an existing block programmatically?

I created the block using yml, here's the configuration:

```
uuid: 67105709-2648-445e-9ddd-8b830a854d8d
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - pixelpin_openid_connect
    - system
  theme:
    - bartik
id: openidconnectlogin
theme: bartik
region: content
weight: 0
provider: null
plugin: pixelpin_openid_connect_login
settings:
  id: pixelpin_openid_connect_login
  label: 'PixelPin OpenID Connect Login'
  provider: pixelpin_openid_connect
  label_display: visible
visibility:
  request_path:
    id: request_path
    pages: /user/login
    negate: false
    context_mapping: {  }
```

The block visibility will change depending on whether a checkbox is checked so i cannot modify the existing block using yml (if that's even possible) unless you can call it in code.

Answer (score 9):

You can load the block and modify the visibility settings:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('openidconnectlogin');
$visibility = $block->getVisibility();
if (isset($visibility['request_path']['pages'])) {
  $visibility['request_path']['pages'] = '/new/path';
  $block->setVisibilityConfig('request_path', $visibility['request_path']);
  $block->save();
}
```

Comment: Hi @4k4, any idea how I can delete the visibility condition completely?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [hook_block_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/8.2.x) or [hook_block_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.2.x).

```
function your_module_block_access(\Drupal\block\Entity\Block $block, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account) {
  // Update your condition according to your requirement.
  if ($operation == 'view' && $block->getPluginId() == 'system_powered_by_block' && $xyz_config == 'xyz') {
    return AccessResult::forbidden()->addCacheableDependency($xyz_config);
  }

  return AccessResult::neutral()->addCacheableDependency($xyz_config);
}
```

You implement `addCacheableDependency` method to avoid caching. Suppose you want to forbid the access if `$xyz_config` is set to "xyz" value. After some time `$xyz_config` variable is changed so access should be allowed in that case. But it won't happen until you add `addCacheableDependency` method and pass the variable.

You can read more about Cache API in D8: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-api

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Callum Updated my answer with example code.

Comment: @SumitMadan - Can you please explain what is $xyz_config, I need to understand and wanted to block is non-cacheable. I created a block using function placeBlock(EntityInterface $entity) () and placed into header region, now I want to change visibility for each block. How can I do this?

Comment: @latikas I have updated my answer. Please check.