# How can I programmatically add or remove a new request_path to block visibility?

Tags: blocks, configuration

It seems like I could utilize the `getVisibilityConditions` method on the block, which returns a `ConditionPluginCollection` object with a `setInstanceConfiguration` method, which is apparently easy enough to use, requiring `$request_path` and `$configuration` arguments. But, the current block visibility request path variable is a string, containing paths separated by commas. How can I update that to either add or remove paths on node save? I know that I'm essentially asking how to manipulate block visibility on the node form, which isn't completely wrong. It just seems like I could be missing something in the API that would allow this kind if thing.

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/226037/47547 - I don't want to vote for a duplicate because the question over there is already marked as a false duplicate.

Comment: @4uk4 it’s open now (your reopen vote is binding because of your score in the related tags)

Comment: @4uk4 your answer at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/226037/47547 is basically what I'm doing, but it doesn't go far enough, since in your suggestion the request_path is just replaced, I want to add or subtract request paths.

Comment: Can you just use implode/explode to convert the string to array and then back after you make adjustments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*But, the current block visibility request path variable is a string, containing paths separated by commas.*

This is the summary display, not the data format saved in config. Here the raw input data is saved along with the new lines entered by the user.

If you want to follow [@sonfd comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/311083/how-can-i-programmatically-add-or-remove-a-new-request-path-to-block-visibility/311087#comment395797_311083) you can rewrite the code of the linked answer:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('openidconnectlogin');
$visibility = $block->getVisibility();
if (isset($visibility['request_path']['pages'])) {
  $pages = $visibility['request_path']['pages'];
  $paths = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $pages));
```

and later

```
  $pages = implode("\n", $paths);
  $visibility['request_path']['pages'] = $pages;
  $block->setVisibilityConfig('request_path', $visibility['request_path']);
  $block->save();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `$pages` array?

Comment: $paths is the array (where you make the adjustments). To make it clear I combine both, the code from the previous answer and the new one.